# file IO performance C

Tags: c, io

I have a question regarding file IO (C language) and its performance issues.

I have an application that does a lot of file I/O (over its lifetime ~3-6hours, about 0.5-0.75TB, of mostly file output).
At the moment my application `sprintf()`s everything into a char string and at the end of a line `write()`s, to a file_descriptor. My string is 1024 characters in length, but can vary anywhere from 64 to 1024. At any rate.

**The question is:** 
 Would it make more sense to make a larger char string (say, 1MB?) and `sprintf()` everything into it before doing the `write()`? Or does it make more sense to skip `sprintf()` completely and simply `write()` directly to the file, assuming the buffering is taken care of by `write()`?

Something I thought of, but unsure if it'll actually accomplish anything in terms of performance: 
What if I had a structure where I store the individual parts of the string, numbers and strings and do a mem_copy of the structure instead? I'm guessing similar to a binary write?

I'm trying to achieve a "buffered" approach or anything that will maximize performance.
The later is that I need to use that file for further processing.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT** 
I did some simple performance comparison with `printf(); + redir` and `sprintf(); write();` 
 I'm simply copying ~20GB to a file.

```
char string[1024];

for(i=0;i<(1<<20)*20;i++)
  printf("%s",string);

~/tmp/tests$ time ./printf.out > testing
real   2m22.101s
user   0m28.214s
sys    0m29.294s
```

as opposed to:

```
char string14[256]; ...etc
for(i=0;1<<(1<<20)*20;i++){
  sprintf(dst_string,"%s%s",dst_string, string14);
  sprintf(dst_string,"%s%s",dst_string, string24);
  sprintf(dst_string,"%s%s",dst_string, string34);
  sprintf(dst_string,"%s%s",dst_string, string44);
  write(fd, dst_string, 1024);
}

~/tmp/tests$ time ./write.out 

real   1m48.206s
user   0m58.544s
sys    0m41.079s
```

The reason for multiple sprintf()s is to simulate copy->buffer and then write buffer.
The time (real anyways) is not as insignificant as some comments may suggest. Granted this is a simple example and maybe in the scheme of computation + IO maybe it won't be.

The thing that I'm a bit confused over the in the printf example, where did that extra time go? user+sys don't add up to real, shouldn't they at least be in the ballpark? Because there is a whole 1:30m missing.

Does this test show any conclusions? sprintf + write > simply print+redir?

Anyways, thank you all for the comments.

Comment: Just using `printf` is probably (almost certainly) better than `sprintf` followed by `write`.

Comment: You should not assume buffering is handled by `write`.  In fact, you should assume that `write` does no buffering at all.

Comment: but that would write to stdout, and I'd have to redirect it, which is slow, limited by the terminal, no? Oh and I don't have fprintf available.

Comment: The OS does most of the buffering for you. To really find out what's going on check the OS documentation.

Comment: to the buffering comment: yes, which is the reason why I'm sprintf-ing everything into a string before committing a write. But is that really so? Does write() do no buffering at all? I wasn't able to find anything regarding that.

Comment: You definitely want a buffered approach. Take a look at the setbuffer functions http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/setbuf/

Comment: If you don't have `fprintf()` available, I'm guessing you might be working on an embedded system with custom-written implementations of `printf()`, etc?  If so, you couldn't necessarily count on anyone else's experience from Linux/Windows/etc, as a custom-written implementation may not behave similarly nor be cached at all.  Then again, maybe it is/does.  In any case, you'd have to test it (i.e. add profiling hooks & compute its performance multiple ways).

Comment: Redirecting is not slow, why do you think it is 'limited by terminal'? It's a pipe from one process to another.

Comment: In any case, if he's writing log info to a file and separately printing other information to the console, redirecting stdout to the file is a severly suboptimal solution.

Comment: Creating output is *not* logging.  Anyone writing software that thinks writing to stdout is equivalent to writing to a console needs to have their education re-examined.  (And in my initial comment, perhaps I should have specified `fprintf` instead of `printf`, but the concept is the same.  `printf` is basically the same as `sprintf` followed by `write`.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell; when you say the same do you mean implementation wise? Or functionality wise?
@zch: Sorry for the terminal comment It was a misunderstanding on my part. But the a simple test I did shows that it is indeed slower. Nevertheless though, I can't redirect it in my application as the application is out-putting other info through stdout and I need the file to be pure with specific info.

Comment: `printf` or `fprintf` is basically doing an `sprintf` into an internal buffer, and when that buffer is full, it does a `write`.  You really don't gain much by implementing that logic, but it is possible to seriously hinder throughput if you get the logic wrong.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `sprintf` and forcing the string length to be constantly recomputed. That doesn't make sense if you're trying to measure performance. You're also forcing `printf` to figure out that you're trying to print one string rather than just using a function that prints just one string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I did some testing on my machine, I got about 60MB/s out of my not-so-modern hardware. That's 3.6GB/minute or 216GB per hour (so 3hours produces about 640GB). I would expect that the time spent in your application is mostly "waiting for the disk", in which case, it makes absolutely no difference what IO methods you use.

But like ALL performance questions, it's not an answer you can find by asking on the internet, or look it up in a book, or whatever. It has to be measured on the system(s) that you are concerned about. Change my skanky old hard-disks for some nicely configured RAID, and you get a much better performance [if it's the right kind of raid system - some are slower than individual disks, as the intention isn't to speed up access but ensure reliability].

You can also make some comparisons:
 1. redirect your software's output to /dev/null - check how long it takes to run your code now. If it's something like 10-100x faster than when you are writing to files, then you know that the way you write now or some other method won't make any difference at all. 
 2. Create similar sized files with `dd if=/dev/zero of=yourfile bs=4k count=largenumber` (largenumber * 4KB = typical file-size) - if your application is writing several files, then write a script that writes several different files like that). If that's much faster than your application, then there's something to be gained by altering the way you do output from your application.

If either of the two things above show that there's a potential for gain, then write some benchmarks that produce a large amount of output in the same way you intend your application to work and see what makes a difference. By all means come back here and ask questions. But my guess is that your application won't run any faster or slower no matter what you do about output mechanisms, because it's all down to "how fast the disk can write".

Comment: Calling `write` without carefully picking buffer sizes instead of using the standard facilities may kill I/O, and using very carefully crafted calls to `write` may increase performance by as much as .00001% (this will vary), so it's probably not correct to say it makes "absolutely no difference".  Calling `write` for each byte is guaranteed to kill the performance!  But all reasonable schemes will be essentially equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I tend to intentionally avoid being overly pedantic in my answers, as it doesn't actually help much. The original question already mentions that there is blocks of 1KB, which should be fine - there's buffering in the OS whichever way you do it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I think I'll have to benchmark my application to see the appropriate buffer to call write() with. And I see where @WilliamPursell is coming from, indeed for even a small amount of savings in time due to IO I'm likely not to see much improvement anyways. Thanks though!